# Using OpenGL ES on Android and iOS at the same time?

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, sdk

We want to create a mobile game for Android and iOS. But we don't want to code it for iOS and Android seperatly via native codes. Is there any way to code it with something like OpenGL library separate from iOS SDK and Android SDK? If it is, is there any tutorial? I couldn't find.

Answer (score 3):

[SpriteBuilder](http://www.spritebuilder.com/) is a development kit for creating 2D games in Objective-C. You can develop the app once and deploy to iOS with Xcode and to Android with [Apportable](http://www.apportable.com/).

Tutorials are available [here](https://www.makegameswith.us/tutorials/getting-started-with-spritebuilder/installing-spritebuilder/).

Comment: SpriteBuilder is based on Cocos2d which has many very wonderful tutorials and is probably one of the most battle tested 2d game engines out there for iOS. I can personally attest there are numerous games out there for Android that utilize this via Apportable; not all of these are Cocos2d/SpriteBuilder http://www.apportable.com/customers but all of them are powered by the same cross platform underpinnings.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as simple as that. The easiest solution is to use special framework, like libgdx http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ (I'm nost saying it's the best choice, I have used it in the past and it worked fine however), unity or gamemaker

Comment: Thank you for the response.. What about it's capabilities? The gallery is fulfilled with bad-looking games =/

Comment: I know what you are talking about, their showcase is lacking. But I guess it has more to do with the fact it's not as simple to use as for example unity or game maker (which are both options you might want to consider). It all depends on your needs. In theory you should be able to create anything with libgdx, but it will take much more time than unity or game maker, as many functions are unavailable.

Comment: OK I got it.. My needs are not much but I want to be future thinker. When I want to change it or make it better, I should be able to do it easily. Thank you.

Comment: So, if we forget my desire(working on both systems) OpenGL or Unity or GameMaker? Which is better?

Comment: That's a question I can't answer as I don't know what game are you talking about and what do you need. If your game is simple and in 2d, and it's your first game, I suggest GameMaker (its surprisingly powerfull, look at Hotline Miami or Gunpoint), if it's in 3d then Unity, it you have a team of programmers and are planning on creating something very unusual, then you can try OpenGL...but that's a general advie, as I said, it depends on the game. Also note, while I made a few simple games in all of those, I'm by no means expert, but that was general advice on my game making courses at Uni.

Comment: My needs are not much for now. We are team with 2 dev and 1 graphic artist. As dev's we are at start and I want to make the best choice at start. I don't want to spend time on something I don't want you use at the future. I will consider your advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: At last, can you say something about Unreal Engine?

Comment: Not from personall experience, but I knew a modder that had a very positive opinion about it. Note that it was in the days before Unity became as popular as it is now. You don't hear much about it these days.

Comment: Thanks again Zyzk.. Good coding.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually libraries for that purpose such libGDX

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a game-engine that deploys on multiple platforms. For example: http://unity3d.com/unity

Comment: What is the difference between the pro and free versions of unity? And why should I pay for Unity? Is it better than OpenGL? Should I took the OpenGL's nativity? Sorry but I don't know about these game engines and I want to start with the best choice for me.

Comment: A game engine like Unity is a layer built on top of OpenGL/DirectX. It handles all existing objects within your 2d/3d environment: their positioning, their movements, what happens if they collide, how light interacts, user-input, loading of 2d/3d-models, etc... These things you would have to program yourself if you were to use OpenGL directly... The free version allows you to develop and deploy games on Windows, Mac and Linux. To deploy on iOs and Android you need the pro-version though.

Answer (score 0):

My commercial product, which is not a game, but is very graphics intensive and uses three-dimensional techniques, uses OpenGL ES 2.0 and runs identically on Android, iOS, Windows, Linux and Mac OS.

The core code is written in C++. On iOS I use the free MetalAngle library to get around the fact that soon Apple will no longer support Open GL.